# JQuery conditional handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to select a `li` element based on a "aria-selected" attribute that is affected to this element after its initialization by a plugin (specifically, it's a [JQuery UI tab](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) element, I want to handle the click on "selected" tabs, and those tabs are added to the DOM dynamically) so I would do this :

```
$("[aria-selected='true']").on('click').method(...);
```

But I need to attach this handler when the element is created, after which it's too late ; I'm creating the element like this:

```
var $thisTab = $('<li></li>');
```

So I need a way to say "attach this handler to this element, but fire it only if it has this attribute, something like:

```
$thisTab.withClass("[aria-selected='true']").on('click').method(...);
```

See, this li contains a `<a href>link</a>` that is "disabled" by the plugin when the tab is "aria-selected". So I cannot just bind the event and test for the attribute, otherwise I'll break the a link on non-selected tabs ; I hope I'm making sense.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want the click handler to be attached to the element even before it is appended to the DOM. ?

Comment: and what make event listener on li and check it in method ...? eg. if(!$(this).attr('xx')) return false;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy Thanks, but no. This is not the issue. I guess I stated my problem incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

this should work for you

```
$("body").on('click', "[aria-selected='true']", function(el){
   // ..method 
}
```

you need to scope your 'future' element to some perm element, like body, document etc..

UPDATE:

if you need to do something after TAB element is created then use something like:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  create: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

or you need to change something when tab is selected use something like:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  activate: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

hth, cheers

Comment: But this fires on `[aria-selected='false']` too (yes, even with `el.preventDefault()` :(

Comment: hm,, this peace of code does not do that, I will try to put some code inline for you to test it

Comment: Your code is ok, only there seems to be an asynchronous call, and in between the click on a "non selected" tab and the function call, somehow the attribute is already set. I think I need a callback, but I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: ditch this method completely and use documentation from here: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/, there are bunch of methods that you can put your logic there..

Comment: can you share url of the page?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) the click handler.

```
$('.container').on('click', '[aria-selected=true]', function () {
  // Do something.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ..

```
 var $thisTab = $('<li></li>');
    $thisTab.on('click', function(){
        var d = $(this).attr('aria-selected');
        if(d=="true") { 
          console.log("here")
        }
    });
```

Comment: This too fires on all `li` elements